# Fill up columns in dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
id  cyear  month     datadate  fyear
1    1988      3          nan    nan
1    1988      4          nan    nan
1    1988      5   1988-05-31   1988
1    1988      6          nan    nan
1    1988      7          nan    nan
1    1988      8          nan    nan
1    1988      9          nan    nan
1    1988     12          nan    nan
1    1989      1          nan    nan
1    1989      2          nan    nan
1    1989      3          nan    nan
1    1989      4          nan    nan 
1    1989      5   1989-05-31   1989
1    1989      6          nan    nan
1    1989      7          nan    nan
1    1989      8          nan    nan
1    1990      8          nan    nan
4    2000      1          nan    nan 
4    2000      2          nan    nan
4    2000      3          nan    nan 
4    2000      4          nan    nan 
4    2000      5          nan    nan
4    2000      6          nan    nan 
4    2000      7          nan    nan 
4    2000      8          nan    nan
4    2000      9          nan    nan
4    2000     10          nan    nan
4    2000     11          nan    nan
4    2000     12   2000-12-31   2000
5    2000     11          nan    nan
```

More specifically, I have a dataframe consisting of monthly (month) data on firms (id) per calendar year (cyear). If the respective row, i.e. month, represents the end of a fiscal year of the firm, the datadate column will denote the respective months end as a date variable and the fyear column will denote the respective fiscal year that just ended.

I now want the fyear value to indicate the respective fiscal year not just in the last month of the respective companies fiscal year, but in every month within the respective fiscal year:

```
id  cyear  month     datadate  fyear
1    1988      3          nan   1988
1    1988      4          nan   1988
1    1988      5   1988-05-31   1988
1    1988      6          nan   1989
1    1988      7          nan   1989
1    1988      8          nan   1989
1    1988      9          nan   1989
1    1988     12          nan   1989
1    1989      1          nan   1989
1    1989      2          nan   1989
1    1989      3          nan   1989
1    1989      4          nan   1989 
1    1989      5   1989-05-31   1989
1    1989      6          nan   1990
1    1989      7          nan   1990
1    1989      8          nan   1990
1    1990      8          nan   1991
4    2000      1          nan   2000 
4    2000      2          nan   2000
4    2000      3          nan   2000
4    2000      4          nan   2000 
4    2000      5          nan   2000
4    2000      6          nan   2000 
4    2000      7          nan   2000 
4    2000      8          nan   2000
4    2000      9          nan   2000
4    2000     10          nan   2000
4    2000     11          nan   2000
4    2000     12   2000-12-31   2000
5    2000     11          nan    nan
```

Note that months may be missing, as evident in case of id 1, and fiscal years may end on different months in fyear=cyear or fyear=cyear+1 (I have included only the former example, one could construct the latter example by adding 1 to the current fyear values of e.g. id 1). Also, the last row(s) of a given firm may not necessarily be its fiscal year end month, as evident in case of id 1. Lastly, there may exist firms for which no information on fiscal years is available.

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: How do we know that the 1990 fiscal year ended? All other fiscal years have a date row at the end. What indicates that this year has ended if they end on different months?

Comment: The fiscal year 1990 in case of id 1 has not ended. There is just one month available, 11 months are missing due to some reason (can be whatever). It just logically follows that june 1989 has to be part of fiscal year 1990, when fiscal year 1989 ended in may.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
def backword_fill(x):
    x = x.bfill()
    x = x.ffill() + x.isna().astype(int)
    return x
    
df.fyear = df.groupby('id')['fyear'].transform(backword_fill)
```

**Output**

```
    id  cyear  month    datadate  fyear
0    1   1988      3        <NA>   1988
1    1   1988      4        <NA>   1988
2    1   1988      5  1988-05-31   1988
3    1   1988      6        <NA>   1989
4    1   1988      7        <NA>   1989
5    1   1988      8        <NA>   1989
6    1   1988      9        <NA>   1989
7    1   1988     12        <NA>   1989
8    1   1989      1        <NA>   1989
9    1   1989      2        <NA>   1989
10   1   1989      3        <NA>   1989
11   1   1989      4        <NA>   1989
12   1   1989      5  1989-05-31   1989
13   1   1989      6        <NA>   1990
14   4   2000      1        <NA>   2000
15   4   2000      2        <NA>   2000
16   4   2000      3        <NA>   2000
17   4   2000      4        <NA>   2000
18   4   2000      5        <NA>   2000
19   4   2000      6        <NA>   2000
20   4   2000      7        <NA>   2000
21   4   2000      8        <NA>   2000
22   4   2000      9        <NA>   2000
23   4   2000     10        <NA>   2000
24   4   2000     11        <NA>   2000
25   4   2000     12  2000-12-31   2000
```

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified further: The last row of a given firm may not necessarily be a fiscal year end. If I understand bfill correctly, it would thus falsely assign such last rows, which are not fiscal year ends, with the potentially wrong fiscal year value.

Comment: @shenflow Then how to evaluate the value of the fiscal year? Ok I got your point let me edit my ans

Comment: It would then be the last fiscal year value (of the respective id) + 1.

Comment: @shenflow Try now

Comment: Sadly, it does not work as it should. E.g. when there would be july 1989 aswell in case of id 1, it would assign both june and july the fyear value 1991, athough they are supposed to be assigned the fyear value 1990.

Comment: Can you include the case in your question? I guess you need to sort based on the month column before doing this. And that x.fill() will just fill NAN values and + x.isna().astype(int) will add 1 to those filled NAN values.

Comment: I edited the question. Please have a look - thanks.